# Autoresizing views on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am currently working on a project and I need to support both portrait and landscape orientation. I have read several books, and all of them tell me to do different things. The view I want to support landscape orientation is simple. It is a UINavigationBar and a UIWebview which is attached to the viewcontrollers view. I have made the view programatically.

Is it correct that I use this method:
    - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:      (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;

I have seen that prior to iOS 3 there was two other methods that were invoked. However I do not target my app below iOS 3.

This code is working but my question is if it is the correct way of doing it programmatically because I don't want to use the InterfaceBuilder on this view.

***Codesnippet*** (working)

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)x duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
   if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(x)) {
      topbar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 480.0f, 44.0f);
   }
}
```

And is it correct that I don't need to apply any animation, iOS will handle this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below two methods to support interface orientations

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{

 //Set the boolean variable for interface orientation condition. 

}


- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
//Set the coordinates of the Views you are using.

}
```

Yes you do not have to worry about the animation part,the OS will take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

The Method you are using is for Custom Changes to the User Interface. You have to do the Animation there yourself. (That's why there is a Duration param) If you just have your 2 Views which need to resize, you can set the Autoresizing mask.

i.e.:

`webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I use the autoresizingMask?  I tried to do as you have written above however it didn't work. I set fixed values in the CGRectMake-structure. Should I write something else there?

Comment: iOS will override these, if the Autoresizing mask is set. for the WebView is think you'll need Webview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;